# Mean values of the prior and posterior distributions

Tags: self-study, bayesian, beta-distribution

I'm having trouble understanding the mean values for a prior and posterior distributions. I know a beta distribution can be found by:

**α /
α+β
.**

Can a prior or posterior value be found using the same formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ \frac{\alpha }{\alpha+\beta}$$

is the formula for estimating expected value of [beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution), it doesn't matter if it is a prior (something assumed), posterior (estimated distribution), likelihood (distribution of the data conditional on parameters), or distribution used for any other purpose.

Comment: The exercise I've been given is to find the mean value of the prior and posterior distributions for a sequence of numbers (p). I'm not sure how to do this really. we have been given the beta distribution as an example to find the mean values.

Comment: Nvm, i've solved my problem